# compare nullable param to non-nullable column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a non-nullable bit column and in my Select statement I would like to only compare it with a nullable param if that nullable param is not null. What's the best way of doing this? There are other conditions in the where clause though I would still like to execute.

Comment: Bit vague, please show what code do you have so far, and what conditions do you need? What are your tables, what indexes do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a typical "kitchen sink" kind of query. It would help your question if you provided some details other than a vague explanation. I think you are looking for something like this.

```
and (@YourParam is null OR [YourBit] = @YourParam)
```

Comment: i think this should be (@YourParam is null OR [YourBit] = @YourParam but I get the gist.

Comment: haha yeah that's what I meant. Will fix it. ;)